# HTML UL jumping up when new element is added

Tags: html, css, sass

I have tried to re-produce an example. I have a button when it is hovered it displays UL element. But the problem I have is If you were to try to add more li elements to UL it jumps up or if deleted any li element from existing list it jumps down. I can't figure out what's causing this. Any help appreciated.

```css
.icon-box {
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -170%);
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: #a05344;
  padding: 15px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

#nav-like {
  position: absolute;
  top: 51.5%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-82%, -40%);
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #C05555;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.movie-img {
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.like-name,
.like-release-date {
  color: #BBBFCA;
  font: 14px Arial, sans-serif font-weight:400;
}

.like-release-date {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.icon-box:hover+#nav-like {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-box">
  <a href="#nav-like" class="btn">click me</a>
</div>
<ul id="nav-like">
  <li class="container">
    <div class="like-img">
      <img src="https://github.com/saedsq/MovieLibrary/blob/master/src/img/nat-1.jpg?raw=true" class="movie-img" alt="rambo">
    </div>
    <div class="like-name">
      <h3>Rambo</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="like-release-date">
      <h3>&#40; 2006 &#41;</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="container">
    <div class="like-img">
      <img src="https://github.com/saedsq/MovieLibrary/blob/master/src/img/nat-1.jpg?raw=true" class="movie-img" alt="rambo">
    </div>
    <div class="like-name">
      <h3>Rambo</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="like-release-date">
      <h3>&#40; 2006 &#41;</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="container">
    <div class="like-img">
      <img src="https://github.com/saedsq/MovieLibrary/blob/master/src/img/nat-1.jpg?raw=true" class="movie-img" alt="rambo">
    </div>
    <div class="like-name">
      <h3>Rambo</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="like-release-date">
      <h3>&#40; 2006 &#41;</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="container">
    <div class="like-img">
      <img src="https://github.com/saedsq/MovieLibrary/blob/master/src/img/nat-1.jpg?raw=true" class="movie-img" alt="rambo">
    </div>
    <div class="like-name">
      <h3>Rambo</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="like-release-date">
      <h3>&#40; 2006 &#41;</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Use one or 2 things. One  use the position property it will keep the drop down in a fixed position. Or you can use the Z-Index property to make the UL appear ontop of the body, so it does not jump.

Comment: I tried both suggestions but it still the same.